# How do I recover a deletion in git?

Tags: git

Ok, so I moved back in my git repo with the **git checkout *HASH*** command.  I then did some modification and forgot I wasn't on the head when I committed changes to the code several times.  I read up on this and found that **git checkout -b *branch-name*** should recover this and it did.  My back-peddling became a branch.

But when looking at gitk, I don't see the things I removed from ***master***.  Using **git log -p** does show the change, but if I try and merge the new branch over to ***master***, it doesn't show up anywhere, probably because I deleted those changes in the branch.

How do I get those changes that I removed on the branch back?

The version of git I'm using is *1.8.4.msygit.0*

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Here are my questions seeking clarification on your question: "some modification" - what modifications exactly? "branch -r branch-name" - what command is this? git branch? Which version of git, because that doesn't do anything sensible on the version of git I'm using. "I deleted those changes in the branch." You mean you deleted your deletions? This is getting confusing...

Comment: @RobinGreen Sorry, I was writing with the assumption that `git` was implied as I wrote that I was writing a question about git. I add it on to the question for additional clarity and add more description.

Comment: But `git branch -r` is for listing remotes. It doesn't make any changes, and it doesn't take a branch name as argument. Are you sure that's what you actually typed?

Comment: @RobinGreen, sorry, you're right.  I was remembering the command incorrectly.  I've fixed it now. So many commands :/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [`git reflog`](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/09/reflog-your-safety-net.html). You can see the list of recent commits, then merge the one you want using `git cherry-pick SHA`.

Here's a few additional resources:

- http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/01/17/restoring-lost-commits.html
- http://ocpsoft.org/tutorials/git/use-reflog-and-cherry-pick-to-restore-lost-commits/